# Doctrine ODM annotations not found in model

Tags: php, doctrine-odm

I am having an issue with an model while the others works succesfully.
I get this error:

```
Type: Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException
Code: 0
Message: [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\Document" in class CAAM\Entities\Payment was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?
File: D:\xampp\htdocs\caam\vendor\doctrine\annotations\lib\Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException.php
Line: 39
```

My model is:

```
namespace CAAM\Entities;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;

/** @ODM\Document(collection="payments") */
class Payment
{}
```

The other models are identical and works!